# How to get Nextjs 13.4+ SRR and Client Components to render properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-server-components

Apologies if I use the wrong terminology when explaining.

I am wondering how to get SSR components and client components to work together and what would be the 'standard/ideal' method to go about this.

I have an an application page under /services/page.tsx which is the parent and is SSR.

```
'use server'

//import React from 'react';
import Grid2 from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2/Grid2';


const Page = () => (
  <Grid2 xs={12} md={9}>
    &nbsp;
  </Grid2>
);

export default Page;
```

Under this route there are similarities so some content is rendered by the /services/layout.tsx and that is found here:

```
interface LayoutProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    params: { locationUuid: string };
}
const Layout = async ({ children, params }: LayoutProps) => {
    const locationResponse = await getLocationUniqueIdentifiers(params.locationUuid, 'uuid');

    if (locationResponse.error !== undefined) {
        return <div>Error</div>;
    }

    const locationIdentifiers = locationResponse.data;

    const servicesResponse = await getServicesByLocationUuid(locationIdentifiers.uuid);

    if (servicesResponse.error !== undefined) {
        return <div>Error</div>;
    }

    const servicesList = servicesResponse.data;

    // add grid around
    return (
        <Grid2 container>
            <Grid2 xs={12} sm={3}>
                <ServicesSidebar servicesList={servicesList} />
            </Grid2>
            {children}
        </Grid2>
    );
}
export default Layout;
```

This part loads fine and there are not issues. There is a nested route within this /services/[serviceId]/page.tsx <- This is where issues start.

This page is ssr and handling all of the data fetch to then pass the data into the client side components. Page.tsx code found here:

```
interface PageProps {
  params: { locationUuid: string; serviceId: string; };
}
const SpecificServicePage = async ({ params }: PageProps) => {
  const locationResponse = await getLocationUniqueIdentifiers(params.locationUuid, 'uuid');

  if (locationResponse.error !== undefined) {
    return (
    <div>
      Location Response Error</div>);
  }

  const locationIdentifiers = locationResponse.data;
  
  const serviceResponse = await getService(params.serviceId);
  

  if (serviceResponse.error !== undefined) {
    return <div>Service Response Error</div>;
  }

  const serviceInformation = serviceResponse.data;
  const nameToLowerCase = serviceInformation.name.toLowerCase();

  const questionsForAllServices = await getQuestionsForAllServiceClaimTypes();
  
  const questionsForSpecificService = await getQuestionsForSpecificServiceClaimType(nameToLowerCase);
  
  if (questionsForAllServices.error !== undefined && questionsForSpecificService.error !== undefined) {
    return <div>Questions Error</div>;
  }
  
  const combinedQuestions = {
    ...questionsForAllServices.data || [],
    ...questionsForSpecificService.data || []
  };
  

  const serviceDataObject = {
    serviceDetails: {
      ...serviceInformation,
    },
    questions: {
      data: combinedQuestions
    },
    locationDetails: {
      ...locationIdentifiers
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ServicesHomePage
        locationIdentifiers={locationIdentifiers}
        service={serviceDataObject}
      />
    </>
  );
}
export default SpecificServicePage;
```

ServicesHomePage is marked with 'use client' and in here it loads some additional client components which has the 'SearchBar'.

The code for ServicesHomePage.tsx:

```
'use client'

import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import Grid2 from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2/Grid2';

import { PatientSearchBar } from '@/entities/reusable/components/PatientSearchBar';
import { PatientResultsTable } from '@/entities/reusable/components/PatientResultsTable';
import { ServiceForm } from '@/entities/services/forms/ServiceForm';
import { PatientHistoryView } from '@/entities/reusable/components/patients/PatientHistoryView';
import ServicesList from '@/app/(authenticated)/location/[locationUuid]/services/ServicesSidebar';
import { SearchBarForPatients } from '@/entities/reusable/components/PatientSearch';

import type { PatientResponseProfileType } from '@/lib/dispense-systems/FRED/dispense-types.types';

const ServicesHomePage = ({ locationIdentifiers, service }: ServicesHomePageProps) => {
  const [patients, setPatients] = useState<PatientResponseProfileType[] | null>(null);
  const [individualPatientData, setIndividualPatientData] = useState<PatientResponseProfileType | null>(null);

  useMemo(() => {
    console.log('hook fired'); //this logs to console
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Grid2 xs={12} sm={6}>
        <SearchBarForPatients
          setPatient={setIndividualPatientData}
        />
        <Divider
          sx={{
            mt: 2,
          }}
        />
        {individualPatientData && locationIdentifiers.air_location_id ? (
          <>
            <ServiceForm
              patient={individualPatientData}
              //setServiceFormSubmission={setServiceFormSubmission}
              setPatientIndividualData={setIndividualPatientData}
              setPatients={setPatients}
              airLocationId={locationIdentifiers.air_location_id}
              locationId={locationIdentifiers.uuid}
              service={service}
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: 'centre',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              mt: 5,
            }}
          >
            <Typography
              variant='h6'
              sx={{
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}
            >
              Please search for a patient.
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        )}
      </Grid2>
      <Grid2 xs={12} md={3}>
        <p>history</p>
        {individualPatientData ? (
          <Box>
            <PatientHistoryView
              medicareNumber={individualPatientData.MedicareNumber}
            />
          </Box>
        ) : (
          null
        )}
      </Grid2>
    </>
  );
}
export default ServicesHomePage;
```

The code for the PatientSearchBar.tsx is:

```
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';

import { getPatientsByLastName } from '@/utilities/server-functions/external-data-functions/dispensary-systems/FRED/dispense';

import type { PatientResponseProfileType } from '@/lib/dispense-systems/FRED/dispense-types.types';

interface PatientSearchBarProps {
    setPatients: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<PatientResponseProfileType[] | null>>;
    setShowPatientList: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}
export const PatientSearchBar = (
    props: PatientSearchBarProps
) => {
    const formik = useFormik({ //! this is probably causing the error as well but not on initial load.
        initialValues: {
            searchTerm: '',
        },
        onSubmit: async (values) => {
            //console.log(values);
            const findPatients = await getPatientsByLastName(values.searchTerm); //! this causes the error
            if (findPatients) {
                props.setPatients(findPatients);
                props.setShowPatientList(true);
            }
        }
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <TextField
                    id='searchTerm'
                    name='searchTerm'
                    label='Search for Patient'
                    value={formik.values.searchTerm}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    InputProps={{
                        endAdornment: (
                            <InputAdornment position='end'>
                                <SearchIcon />
                            </InputAdornment>
                        )
                    }}
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The SearchBar component renders fine however the moment a hook needs to be called the following error will populate:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.
```

For reference the files marked as 'use server' and 'use client' are:

- layout.tsx = 'use server'
- services/page.tsx = 'use server'
- services/[serviceId]/page.tsx = 'use server'
- ServicesHomePage.tsx = 'use client'
- SearchBar = 'use client'

To fix the issue I've tried to:

- force putting 'use client' / 'use server' at the top of every .tsx file
- wrapping pages in react fragments <> </>
- tested different hooks such as useMemo with console.logs to see if they fired (useMemo works the others do not)

While googling the error looks like it should be firing off any hook and async/await however using useMemo does not cause an issue.

Referencing the nextjs [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns) shouldn't adding the 'use client'/'use server' create the boundaries for rendering and if it doesn't how can I get the server pages to not cause the entire tree to render as server side?

Comment: Please add the code for `ServicesHomePage` to the question.

Comment: Hey Robin - thanks for the reply. Have added those now. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any client components, where you have `await` in that flle?

Comment: Yep so the PatientSearchBar has an await call on the formik.onSubmit which calls a server action and updates states. This onSubmit action is wrapped in an async function. 

Just for reference, prior to changing the layout files and page.tsx files into 'use server' the above worked with 'use client' at the top.